# Is it possible to get a HMONITOR Handle from a Windows Object Manager Path?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a path that looks like this:

`\\?\DISPLAY#IVM1A3E#5&1778d8b3&1&UID260#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}`

From that I would like to get a [`HMONITOR` handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/hmonitor-and-the-device-context).

Using [WinObj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj) I can see under GLOBAL?? that it's a Symbolic link to some `\Device\<number>`.

How would I go about doing something like that?

**Edit:**

The path can be split in three parts. First the `\\?\` prefix, then second `DISPLAY#IVM1A3E#5&1778d8b3&1&UID260` if the `#` are replaced by `\` it is the same as the [device instance ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-instance-ids). Thirdly `{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}` is the [GUID for Monitor devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-devinterface-monitor).

With the device instance ID I can walk the device tree using [`CM_Get_Child`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_child) and [`CM_Get_Sibling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_sibling), checking the device names with [`CM_Get_Device_ID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_device_idw). But that only gives me a `DEVINST` not a `HMONITOR`.

Comment: Where did you get the \\?\... device path from in the first place?

Comment: The registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wisp\Pen\Digimon`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Connecting and configuring displays (CCD) API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/connecting-and-configuring-displays), especially the [The QueryDisplayConfig function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig) which retrieves information about all possible display paths for all display devices, or views, in the current setting.

With the following code, you'll get the correspondance between a Device Path and a Monitor (and its handle).

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // get all paths
    UINT pathCount;
    UINT modeCount;
    if (GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS, &pathCount, &modeCount))
        return 0;

    std::vector<DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO> paths(pathCount);
    std::vector<DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO> modes(modeCount);
    if (QueryDisplayConfig(QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS, &pathCount, paths.data(), &modeCount, modes.data(), nullptr))
        return 0;

    // enum all monitors => (handle, device name)>
    std::vector<std::tuple<HMONITOR, std::wstring>> monitors;
    EnumDisplayMonitors(nullptr, nullptr, [](HMONITOR hmon, HDC hdc, LPRECT rc, LPARAM lp)
    {
        MONITORINFOEX mi = {};
        mi.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFOEX);
        GetMonitorInfo(hmon, &mi);
        auto monitors = (std::vector<std::tuple<HMONITOR, std::wstring>>*)lp;
        monitors->push_back({ hmon, mi.szDevice });
        return TRUE;
    }, (LPARAM)&monitors);

    // for each path, get GDI device name and compare with monitor device name
    for (UINT i = 0; i < pathCount; i++)
    {
        DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME deviceName = {};
        deviceName.header.type = DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_TARGET_NAME;
        deviceName.header.size = sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_TARGET_DEVICE_NAME);
        deviceName.header.adapterId = paths[i].targetInfo.adapterId;
        deviceName.header.id = paths[i].targetInfo.id;
        if (DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo((DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER*)&deviceName))
            continue;

        wprintf(L"Monitor Friendly Name : %s\n", deviceName.monitorFriendlyDeviceName);
        wprintf(L"Monitor Device Path   : %s\n", deviceName.monitorDevicePath);

        DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_DEVICE_NAME sourceName = {};
        sourceName.header.type = DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_GET_SOURCE_NAME;
        sourceName.header.size = sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_DEVICE_NAME);
        sourceName.header.adapterId = paths[i].targetInfo.adapterId;
        sourceName.header.id = paths[i].sourceInfo.id;
        if (DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo((DISPLAYCONFIG_DEVICE_INFO_HEADER*)&sourceName))
            continue;

        wprintf(L"GDI Device Name       : %s\n", sourceName.viewGdiDeviceName);

        // find the monitor with this device name
        auto mon = std::find_if(monitors.begin(), monitors.end(), [&sourceName](std::tuple<HMONITOR, std::wstring> t)
        {
            return !std::get<1>(t).compare(sourceName.viewGdiDeviceName);
        });
        wprintf(L"Monitor Handle        : %p\n", std::get<0>(*mon));
        wprintf(L"\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On my PC (with 2 monitors), it will output something like this:

```
Monitor Friendly Name : C27HG7x
Monitor Device Path   : \\?\DISPLAY#SAM0E16#7&307b5912&0&UID1024#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}
GDI Device Name       : \\.\DISPLAY2
Monitor Handle        : 0000000000160045

Monitor Friendly Name : DELL U2715H
Monitor Device Path   : \\?\DISPLAY#DELD069#7&307b5912&0&UID1028#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7}
GDI Device Name       : \\.\DISPLAY1
Monitor Handle        : 0000000000020083
```

Note you can also get the same information using WinRT's [DisplayManager class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.display.core.displaymanager) => [DisplayView class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.display.core.displayview) => [Paths property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.display.core.displayview.paths), [DisplayPath class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.display.core.displaypath), => [Target property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.display.core.displaypath.target) => [TryGetMonitor function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.display.core.displaytarget.trygetmonitor)