How to get a monitor's actual Identifier/Name from a DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC?
I am enumerating DXGI Adapters and their Outputs and I am using the GDI function EnumDisplayDevices to retrieve the names.
However, all my outputs receive the name "Generic PnP Monitor". Which is fairly... meaningless.
typedef struct D3D10MODELIST {
    long nModes;
    DXGI_MODE_DESC* modes;
} D3D10MODELIST;

typedef struct D3D10OUTPUTLIST {
    IDXGIOutput* output;
    D3D10MODELIST modes[NUM_FORMATS];
} D3D10OUTPUTLIST;

typedef struct D3D10ADAPTER {
    IDXGIAdapter* adapter;
    long nOutputs;
    D3D10OUTPUTLIST* outputs;
} D3D10ADAPTER;

typedef struct D3D10INFO {
    long nAdapters;
    D3D10ADAPTER* adapters;
} D3D10INFO;


char* GetOutputName(D3D10INFO* info, long adapter, long output, char * buffer, long bufferSize) {
    DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC desc;
    ABORT_IF_FAILED(IDXGIAdapter_GetDesc(info->adapters[adapter].outputs[output].output, &desc),"Error Getting Output Description");

    MONITORINFOEXA monitorInfo;
    monitorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(monitorInfo);
    GetMonitorInfoA(desc.Monitor, (LPMONITORINFO)&monitorInfo);

    DISPLAY_DEVICEA displayDevice;
    displayDevice.cb = sizeof(displayDevice);
    EnumDisplayDevices(monitorInfo.szDevice,0,&displayDevice,EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME);

    snprintf(buffer,bufferSize, "%ld: %s (%s)",output, displayDevice.DeviceString,displayDevice.DeviceID);
    return buffer;
}

This gives me the following example output:

Output: 1: Generic PnP Monitor (\?\DISPLAY#LEN1144#7&27916b9d&0&UID516#{e6f07b5f-ee97-4a90-b076-33f57bf4eaa7})

What I want is probably the name as seen in Windows' Device Manager:


You can't do that using only DXGI, you'll have to use other APIS for example the CCD APIs like demonstrated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74605112/403671 the AdapterID is the link.
