How to get friendly name that belongs to an HMONITOR handle in Windows?
I need the friendly name that belongs to a handle of type HMONITOR.
WMI allows me to list all the monitors connected with all the information I'll ever need, but how can I connect this information to the monitor handles I obtain via EnumDisplayMonitors?
DDCCI is not an option, as the monitor in question does not provide its capabilities.
I found GetMonitorInfoW(), but that only gives me Display1 and Display2 as szDevice, so thats not really helpful.
Below, you can find my current approach in Python. All you need to run the code is to be on Windows and to install wmi via pip. Feel free to answer in C++ or any other language, really :)
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import (
    DWORD,
    RECT,
    BOOL,
    HMONITOR,
    HDC,
    LPARAM,
    HANDLE,
    BYTE,
    WCHAR, WORD, SHORT,
)

def get_vcps():
    vcps = []
    hmonitors = []
    try:
        def _callback(hmonitor, hdc, lprect, lparam):
            hmonitors.append(HMONITOR(hmonitor))
            del hmonitor, hdc, lprect, lparam
            return True  # continue enumeration

        MONITORENUMPROC = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, HMONITOR, HDC, ctypes.POINTER(RECT), LPARAM)
        callback = MONITORENUMPROC(_callback)
        if not ctypes.windll.user32.EnumDisplayMonitors(0, 0, callback, 0):
            raise RuntimeError("Call to EnumDisplayMonitors failed")
    except OSError as err:
        raise RuntimeError("failed to enumerate VCPs") from err
    print("hmonitors:")
    for hmonitor in hmonitors:
        print(f"hmonitor: {hmonitor}")
    # WMI provides a list of the friendly names of the monitors, but not the handles:
    print("WMI monitor IDs:")
    for monitor in get_wmi_monitor_id():
        print(monitor)
    return vcps

def get_wmi_monitor_id():
    import wmi
    c = wmi.WMI(namespace='root\\wmi')
    monitors = c.WmiMonitorID()
    monitor_data = []
    for monitor in monitors:
        monitor_info = {
            "active": monitor.Active,
            "InstanceName": monitor.InstanceName,
            "ManufacturerName": ''.join(chr(c) for c in monitor.ManufacturerName if c != 0),
            "ProductCodeID": monitor.ProductCodeID,
            "SerialNumberID": ''.join(chr(c) for c in monitor.SerialNumberID if c != 0),
            "UserFriendlyName": ''.join(chr(c) for c in monitor.UserFriendlyName if c != 0),
            "WeekOfManufacture": monitor.WeekOfManufacture,
            "YearOfManufacture": monitor.YearOfManufacture
        }
        monitor_data.append(monitor_info)
    return monitor_data

get_vcps()


Have you tried EnumDisplayDevices()? Also, in WMI, the Win32_DesktopMonitor class has a DeviceID which appears to be related to its HMONITOR.

You can use the CCD API https://stackoverflow.com/a/74605112/403671 or WinRT https://stackoverflow.com/a/78179702/403671

Win32_DesktopMonitor: Only returns my modern Monitor, the other one is not even listed.
CCD API: Only returns my modern Monitor, the other old one is listed, but DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo fails.
WinRT: Didn't check
EnumDisplayDevices(): Works like a charm (took a while though)
Thanks to both of you!

Probably a very brittle solution that has to be refined while I get more user feedback. But for my setup it works like a charm.
import binascii
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD, WCHAR, HMONITOR, BOOL, HDC, RECT, LPARAM, CHAR
from typing import NamedTuple, Optional, Dict

import wmi


class DISPLAY_DEVICE(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("cb", DWORD),
        ("DeviceName", WCHAR * 32),
        ("DeviceString", WCHAR * 128),
        ("StateFlags", DWORD),
        ("DeviceID", WCHAR * 128),
        ("DeviceKey", WCHAR * 128)
    ]


class MONITORINFOEXA(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("cbSize", DWORD),
        ("rcMonitor", RECT),
        ("rcWork", RECT),
        ("dwFlags", DWORD),
        ("szDevice", CHAR * 32)
    ]


_DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE = 0x1


def _get_display(device_name):
    # only return the part between \\\\.\\ and \\ or until the end of the string
    import re
    match = re.search(r'\\\\\.\\(.*?)(\\|$)', device_name)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    return None


def _handle_to_display_mapping():
    hmonitors = []
    mapping = {}
    try:
        def _callback(hmonitor, hdc, lprect, lparam):
            hmonitors.append(HMONITOR(hmonitor))
            del hmonitor, hdc, lprect, lparam
            return True  # continue enumeration

        MONITORENUMPROC = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, HMONITOR, HDC, ctypes.POINTER(RECT), LPARAM)
        callback = MONITORENUMPROC(_callback)
        if not ctypes.windll.user32.EnumDisplayMonitors(0, 0, callback, 0):
            raise RuntimeError("Call to EnumDisplayMonitors failed")
    except OSError as _:
        raise RuntimeError("failed to enumerate VCPs")

    for hmonitor in hmonitors:
        monitor_info = MONITORINFOEXA()
        monitor_info.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(MONITORINFOEXA)
        if not ctypes.windll.user32.GetMonitorInfoA(hmonitor, ctypes.byref(monitor_info)):
            raise RuntimeError("Call to GetMonitorInfoA failed")
        mapping[_get_display(monitor_info.szDevice.decode("ascii"))] = hmonitor
    return mapping


def _display_to_device_id_mapping(only_active=True):
    i = 0
    devices = []
    # first get all display devices:
    while True:
        display_device = DISPLAY_DEVICE()
        display_device.cb = ctypes.sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE)
        if not ctypes.windll.user32.EnumDisplayDevicesW(None, i, ctypes.byref(display_device), 0):
            break
        if not only_active or display_device.StateFlags & _DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE:
            devices.append(display_device.DeviceName)
        i += 1
    mapping = {}
    for device_name in devices:
        j = 0
        while True:
            display_device = DISPLAY_DEVICE()
            display_device.cb = ctypes.sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE)
            # Query each monitor associated with the adapter
            if not ctypes.windll.user32.EnumDisplayDevicesW(device_name, j, ctypes.byref(display_device), 0):
                break
            if not only_active or display_device.StateFlags & _DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE:
                mapping[_get_display(display_device.DeviceName)] = display_device.DeviceID
            j += 1
    return mapping


def _device_id_to_f_name_mapping():
    c = wmi.WMI(namespace='root\\wmi')
    monitors = c.WmiMonitorID()
    mapping = {}
    for monitor in monitors:
        mapping[monitor.InstanceName] = ''.join(chr(c) for c in monitor.UserFriendlyName if c != 0)
    return mapping


def _display_to_handle_and_f_name_mapping(dmapping, hmapping, nmapping):
    dmapping_parts = {k: tuple(v.split('\\')) for k, v in dmapping.items()}
    nmapping_parts = {tuple(k.split('\\')): v for k, v in nmapping.items()}

    mapping: Dict[str, Optional[ctypes.POINTER]] = {display: None for display in hmapping.keys()}
    for device_id_parts, f_name in nmapping_parts.items():
        for did_part in device_id_parts:
            # we need to find the corresponding display in the dmapping parts
            for display, display_parts in dmapping_parts.items():
                if did_part in display_parts and display in hmapping:
                    mapping[display] = (f_name, hmapping[display])
    return mapping


def _get_monitor_descriptions() -> list[NamedTuple]:
    import pyedid
    c = wmi.WMI(namespace='wmi')
    monitors = c.WmiMonitorDescriptorMethods()
    edid_data = []
    for monitor in monitors:
        edid = bytes(monitor.WmiGetMonitorRawEEdidV1Block(0)[0])
        if edid:
            edid_hex = binascii.hexlify(edid).decode('ascii')
            edid_data.append(pyedid.parse_edid(edid_hex))
    return edid_data


def display_to_handle_and_f_name_mapping():
    dmapping = _display_to_device_id_mapping(True)
    hmapping = _handle_to_display_mapping()
    nmapping = _device_id_to_f_name_mapping()
    return _display_to_handle_and_f_name_mapping(dmapping, hmapping, nmapping)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(display_to_handle_and_f_name_mapping())

